# Custom file properties in Dropbox Core API?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

In the Google Drive API there is something called custom file properties - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties - and they can be used to add your own as key/value pairs:

```
{
  'key':        'additionalID',
  'value':      '8e8aceg2af2ge72e78',
  'visibility': 'PRIVATE'
}
```

I would like to do the same in a desktop Java application with the Dropbox Core API, but I cannot find anything. Am I missing something or is this simply not available in Dropbox Core API?

If there is something, please provide an example of how it would be used in Java. Thanks!

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer something exactly like this, but you could use datastores to store information like this, keyed by file path: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore

Comment: Ok, thanks, I looked into it quickly, but it's hard to see how it would be used to associate with the Core API and the actions on files there... Could you provide an answer and maybe an example how the datastore could be used to save data about a file and how it would refer to it? Only if you provide an answer would I be able to credit you if this is in fact the answer in any case. Thanks!

Comment: Also, another question about this as a solution: as I mentioned, this is a Java desktop application, and I couldn't find an SDK for the Datastore for this - only for Android, OS X, Python, etc...

Comment: I don't have any good resources to point you to, so I won't consider a full answer, but the basic idea would be to have a table of records, with one record per file, and each record could have a "path" field, with the string of the path for the relevant file. The rest of the fields on that record could then be the other information you want to store. This breaks if the file is moved or renamed unfortunately. Also, there's currently no Java SDK for the Datastore API, but you can implement against the Datastore API HTTP endpoints: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/http

Comment: (There are others ways to structure this of course, but the one record per file seems the simplest to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Dropbox has begun to implement this feature.
In API v2 there are such endpoints:

```
properties/template/add
properties/template/get
properties/add
properties/remove
properties/update
```

and so on.

Details looks at [API Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-properties-add).
But all of them are marked as:

> PREVIEW - may change or disappear without notice

Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API now offers the (now non-preview) ability to add arbitrary key/value data to Dropbox files via "file properties":

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_properties

If you're using an official Dropbox SDK, there will also be corresponding methods for these endpoints.